# Show no open ball in $C[0,1]$ is contained in the space of all Lipschitz-continuous functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is a question I encountered in a textbook exercise. Here $C[0,1]$ is the space of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with the sup metric, $d(f,g):=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ for $f,g\in C[0,1]$.

Let $f_0$ be an arbitrary element of $C[0,1]$; for an $\varepsilon>0$, let $B(f_0, \varepsilon):=\{f\in C[0,1]:d(f,g)<\varepsilon\}$ be an open ball in $C[0,1]$. When $f_0$ is not Lipschitz-continuous, the claim obviously follows. Suppose $f_0$ is Lipschitz-continuous. For me, the claim seems to require finding a continuous function that is 'close' to $f_0$ (contained in $B(f_0,\varepsilon)$) but not Lipschiz-continuous. I don't have any clue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose some $f_0 \in C[0,1]$, and $\epsilon>0$. Let $f_1$ be a piecewise affine function such that $\|f_0-f_1\|_\infty < {\epsilon \over 2}$. (Actually, $f_1$ just needs to be smooth in the neighbourhood of $0$ for this proof, a nearby polynomial would work fine too.)

Now let $f_2(x) = f_1(x)+ {\epsilon \over 2} \sqrt{x}$. Clearly $\|f_1-f_2\|_\infty \le {\epsilon \over 2}$, and $f_2$ is not Lipschitz at $x=0$.

Finally, we have $\|f_2-f_0\|_\infty \le \|f_2-f_1\|_\infty  + \|f_1-f_0\|_\infty  < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When $f_0$ is Lipschitz, we can simply let $f_1(x) = f_0(x) + \varepsilon \sqrt{x}$. Such an $f_1$ is not Lipschitz at $x=0$ and $\|f_1 - f_0 \|_\infty < \varepsilon$. The affine function approximation is only necessary when $f_0$ is not Lipschitz. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: That will work. Basically I wanted $f_1$ to be more or less the same as $f_0$ but I wanted it to be smooth at $x=0$ so that $f_2$ is obviously not Lipschitz at $x=0$ (since the derivative will be $f_1'(\epsilon)+{1 \over 2 \sqrt{\epsilon}}$ for small $\epsilon$).